# NotificationCenter addObserver

Tags: ios, swift

I want to update the display of my app each time it comes to the foreground. I am using the following code in `ViewDidLoad` which seems to be working fine.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.updateDisplay), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil)
```

Do I need to remove the observer at any point?

Comment: Here's an interesting video about `NotificationCenter` observers. They discuss an alternative approach to removing them near the end: https://talk.objc.io/episodes/S01E27-typed-notifications-part-1

Comment: @humanoid : Sunil Chauhan was absolutely correct, You can accept his answer. Tried the code on iOS 9 device and realised that notification centre will not trigger the method on deinited object! Tested both method based and block based API's in iOS 9 and iOS 10, both works absolutely fine. You need not remove the observer anymore

Answer (score 3):

As of iOS 9.0, you don't need to remove selector-based observers. Have look at this [release note:](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/Foundation/RN-Foundation/index.html#10_11NotificationCenter)

> In OS X 10.11 and iOS 9.0 NSNotificationCenter and NSDistributedNotificationCenter will no longer send notifications to registered observers that may be deallocated. If the observer is able to be stored as a zeroing-weak reference the underlying storage will store the observer as a zeroing weak reference, alternatively if the object cannot be stored weakly (i.e. it has a custom retain/release mechanism that would prevent the runtime from being able to store the object weakly) it will store the object as a non-weak zeroing reference. This means that observers are not required to un-register in their deallocation method. The next notification that would be routed to that observer will detect the zeroed reference and automatically un-register the observer. If an object can be weakly referenced notifications will no longer be sent to the observer during deallocation; the previous behavior of receiving notifications during dealloc is still present in the case of non-weakly zeroing reference observers. Block based observers via the -[NSNotificationCenter addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock] method still need to be un-registered when no longer in use since the system still holds a strong reference to these observers. Removing observers (either weakly referenced or zeroing referenced) prematurely is still supported. CFNotificationCenterAddObserver does not conform to this behavior since the observer may not be an object.

Comment: Very good observation, Learnt something new today! If I could I would have accepted this as answer anyway I can't hence up vote :D

Answer (score 0):

You can call `NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil)` in `viewWillDisappear` method.
But this will remove your observer when you moves from that screen to other, so if you want to add observer again for that screen move your

`NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.updateDisplay), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil)` to `viewWillAppear`

Its always good practice to remove it, otherwise as long as your screen is in stack and app comes to foreground, it will try to call that method again and again.

Comment: Does viewWillAppear get called when coming from the background?

Comment: Yes, when you are on same controller where you added notification, first application did enter foreground will get called and then viewWIllAppear